# Key Vault 403 during getting access via MSI token

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I need to get an access token from my keyvault via MSI.

1. I follow the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-qs-configure-portal-windows-vm) to enable MSI. MSI is enabled and the necessary
   extension was installed.
2. I perform this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-howto-assign-access-portal) to add access control of Key Vault for my VM. VM is contributor of KeyVault
3. I try to get AC according to this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-tutorial-linux-vm-access-nonaad) and gets 403 when I try to get access to the Key Vault.

Step 3 in details:

1. `curl http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token --data "resource=https://vault.azure.net" -H Metadata:true`
2. `curl https://<YOUR-KEY-VAULT-URL>/secrets/<secret-name>?api-version=2016-10-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>"`

When I run step 2 I get 403 error.

I tried to replace 'https://vault.azure.net' to 'https://' but I got another error:

```
{"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS50001: The application named https://<YOUR-KEY-VAULT-URL> was not found in the tenant named <A tenant ID>.This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 7365f8f5-791f-4131-88f8-9466cadc4d00\r\nCorrelation ID: e18e0e5e-966e-460b-9b61-16decf97dff4\r\nTimestamp: 2017-12-12 11:18:01Z","error_codes":[50001],"timestamp":"2017-12-12 11:18:01Z","trace_id":"7365f8f5-791f-4131-88f8-9466cadc4d00","correlation_id":"e18e0e5e-966e-460b-9b61-16decf97dff4"}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the VM service principal in Key Vault's *Policies*. Having Contributor on the Key Vault allows the principal to perform operations through the ARM API, but what it needs to access is the Key Vault API. That requires you to add the principal some permissions on the Policies tab.